# Qt cannot save pixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpixmap

Hello i have a strange problem to save pixmap.

My Widget Header

```
public:
  QPixmap *base;  //Base Poses
  QPixmap *Hair;  //Hair
  QPixmap *Composited;  //Final Composition

  bool compisition = false;

  void Composite();
```

My Widget Cpp

At paintEvent

```
 base = &pic;
    Hair = &hairs;

    if(compisition)
    {
        QPixmap pix(128,192);
        QPainter *p = new QPainter(&pix);

        p->drawPixmap(0,0,128,192,*base);
        p->drawPixmap(0,0,128,192,*Hair);

        Composited = &pix;
        compisition = false;
    }
void AnimPreview::Composite()
{
    compisition = true;
    this->update();


}
```

At main form source

```
void MainWindow::on_commandLinkButton_clicked()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                               tr("Save Sprite file"),
                                               "",tr("File PNG (*.png)"));

    const QPixmap *pix = ui->SpriteFront->pixmap();

    if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile files(file);
        files.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        ui->SpriteFront->Composite();
        ui->SpriteFront->Composited->save(&files,"PNG");
    }
}
```

When i try to save a file, the process work but whit on error

An unhandled win32 exception

For more information
complete code here

https://pastebin.com/GtaVCXGf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have avoided reviewing where the error can be generated since there are many possible sources of the problem, among them the following:

- It is not necessary that you create `QPixmap` pointers since in the end you will have the job of eliminating it from memory.
- The same happens with `QPainter` since it only needs to be a local variable, in addition to that the painting is not done immediately, to be sure that it is painted you must call its `end()` method.
- `paintEvent` is a protected method, so by design we prefer it to remain so.
- It is not necessary to use a `QFile` to save an image, you can directly pass the filename to it.

Considering all the above, we obtain the following:

***.h**

```
#ifndef ANIMPREVIEW_H
#define ANIMPREVIEW_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

class AnimPreview : public QLabel
{
public:
    AnimPreview(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void Rotate(int value);
    void Composite();
    void Create(int _sex, int _hair);
    QPixmap Composited;

private:
    int sex = 0;
    int hair = 0;
    bool draw = true;

    int rotation = 0;
    const int offsetX = 16;
    const int offsetY = 32;

    QPixmap base;
    QPixmap Hair;
    bool compisition = false;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // ANIMPREVIEW_H
```

***.cpp**

```
#include "animpreview.h"

#include <QPainter>

AnimPreview::AnimPreview(QWidget *parent):QLabel(parent)
{
}

void AnimPreview::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){

    QPainter p(this);
    QPixmap pic;
    QPixmap hairs;

    if(draw)
    {
        //Sesso
        switch(sex)
        {
        case 0:
            pic.load(":/Male/Base/Res/man_f.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            pic.load(":/Male/Base/Res/woman_f.png");

            break;
        }

        //capelli
        if(sex == 1)
        {
            switch(hair)
            {
            case 1:
                hairs.load(":/Female/Hair/Res/7_aqua.png");
                break;
            case 2:
                hairs.load(":/Female/Hair/Res/5_gold.png");
                break;
            }
        }

        if(sex == 0)
        {
            switch (hair)
            {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                hairs.load(":/Male/Hair/Res/1_aqua.png");
                break;
            case 2:
                hairs.load(":/Male/Hair/Res/14_black.png");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    p.drawPixmap(width()/2 - offsetX,height()/2 - offsetY,pic,0,rotation,32,48);
    p.drawPixmap(width()/2 - offsetX,height()/2 - offsetY,hairs,0,rotation,32,48);
    p.drawRect(0,0, width()-1, height()-1);

    base = pic;
    Hair = hairs;

    if(compisition)
    {
        QPixmap pix(128,192);
        QPainter p(&pix);

        p.drawPixmap(0,0,128,192, base);
        p.drawPixmap(0,0,128,192, Hair);

        p.end();

        Composited = pix;
        compisition = false;
    }
}

void AnimPreview::Rotate(int value)
{
    rotation = value;
    update();
}

void AnimPreview::Create(int _sex, int _hair)
{
    sex = _sex;
    hair = _hair;
    draw = true;
}

void AnimPreview::Composite()
{
    compisition = true;
    update();
}
```

---

```
void MainWindow::on_commandLinkButton_clicked()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                tr("Save Sprite file"),
                                                "",tr("File PNG (*.png)"));

    if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
        ui->SpriteFront->Composite();
        ui->SpriteFront->Composited.save(file,"PNG");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing anything other than painting in the `paintEvent` is a UX bug. The pixmaps can be loaded on demand when the `sex` or `hairs` are set - and they can be loaded asynchronously on a worker thread, so as not to block the gui. Then, once the picture is available, the worker signals it, it gets set on the widget, and thus the widget is updated and finally painted with everything ready. Also note that with the default backend, the `QImage` to `QPixmap` roundtrip is very cheap, because the pixmap is just a thin wrapper around an internal `QImage`.

Comment: @KubaOber 
You are absolutely right, I look at other errors, and not in the design of the application. Later I will update it. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, whit your code work without error. but pixmap is not saved.  Screen1° https://s14.postimg.org/g88yt90ht/cattura.png , Screen2° https://s14.postimg.org/ueopom8tt/cattura.png, Image is empty. for wath?